# Hashing user password - Identity Server

Tags: c#, identityserver4, password-hash

I'm currently working with Identity Server 4, at present when the user logs in I need to hash their provided password and then compare with the password stored in the database (also hashed)

After some searching, I was linked to the `PasswordHasher` within Identity Server to handle this:

```
  var _hasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();
  var hashpassword = _hasher.HashPassword(user, context.Password);
```

`User` is my custom class that inherits from `IdentityUser`, however, when checking the hashed password against the one in the database the hash is completely different, I have double checked the password and I can confirm it's correct.

Can anyone suggest why I maybe seeing a different hash compared to the one in the database?

Comment: How did you hash the passwords already in the database?

Comment: It was done automatically when using await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password1!");

Comment: Use `_userManager.PasswordHasher` instead of instantiating a new one. IPasswordHasher is an interface, so UserManager might not be using the same implementation as you, and if it is, it might specify different properties such as the hashing algorithm and the number of iterations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you hash a password with `PasswordHasher<T>.HashPassword` you will get a total different result because of the [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

To verify such hashed salted passwords use the given method [`IPasswordHasher<T>.VerifyPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ipasswordhasher-1.verifyhashedpassword?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_IPasswordHasher_1_VerifyHashedPassword__0_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks Sir Rufo.